# How to detect if a trigger is fired for an insert or update?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to make a table in my database that has all of the history of all DML statements that occur in a given table. The `LOG` table is like this:

| id | event | ts | record |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | update | 2020-01-01 | record1 |
| 2 | delete | 2020-01-02 | record2 |

LOG table has a sequence for auto-incrementing the `ID` column and TS default is `NOW`.

Do I need to create a sequence for every statement first or I can just create triggers for `AFTER` a DML statement is fired?

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE
  ACTIVE AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON TableA
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LOG (event,record)
     SELECT record FROM TableA; # what I need to add here to set the event = UPDATE,INSERT or DELETE?
END
```

Can I use something like this in my triggers with a statement to add an event values?

Comment: since it is about logging you might want to do it `in autonomous transaction` so the log record would not disappear in case some error happens and rolls back the logging transaction

Comment: @Arioch'The Only if it makes sense for the logging of the update event to be retained even if the actual update itself was rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect the type of event, you can use the [`INSERTING`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars-inserting) or [`UPDATING`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars-updating) (or [`DELETING`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars-deleting)) context variables.

As an aside, do not use `SELECT record FROM TableA` in a trigger on `TableA`, instead use the [`NEW` context](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-oldnew) (or `OLD` for a delete).

The solution would look something like this:

```sql
insert into LOG (event, record) 
  values (case when :inserting then 'insert' when :updating then 'update' end, new.record);
```

Comment: Is this availiable in `firebird 2.5`?

Comment: @T0ny1234 Yes, these have been available since Firebird 1.5

Comment: And you can check the [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html) as well.